# In Excel, how can I highlight two cells based on a condition of either cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

How can I highlight two cells based on a condition of either cell?  Given two rows of data "PCT CHG" and "WEEK", I would like to highlight both cells if the value in "PCT_CHG" is >=25% or the value in "WEEK" = 1.

I applied conditional formatting in the following manner:

1. Highlighted A2:B2
2. Rule: `=OR(AND(A2>=0.25,ISNUMBER(A2)),B2=1)`
3. Applies to: `Sheet1!$A$2:$B$10`

I ended up with the following:

[image]

Whereas, my desired output is:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=OR(AND($A2>=0.25,ISNUMBER($A2)),$B2=1)`

Comment: Yes, this is correct!  I was just about to answer my own question after going nuts for the last hour!  Apparently, it has to do w/ relative referencing of the cells.  Thank you for the response!

Comment: @enter_display_name_here Yes, by using relative references for rows but absolute references for columns Excel interprets that to be extended to the whole region accordingly.